# Listview items are not clickable

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I use 'ListFragment' to list items in a listview. The listview's xml is:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp" />
```

And the XML layout for the items is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fromId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fromName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also have the the following in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    MyItem item = (MyItem)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
}
```

However, the items are not clickable.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where calling `setOnItemClickListener`?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I don't need to call `setOnItemClickListener` because I'm using `ListFragment`. However, I do indeed override `onListItemClick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with

```
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Item clicked: " +  [position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Your Staff
        }
    });
```

Or

```
 getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); // onActivityCreated()


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
```

**Edited**

```
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Item clicked: " +  [position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        MyItem item = (MyItem)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
```

Comment: Not necessary because this code is handled in `ListFragment`.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono . Let me feedback please .

Comment: Your edited answer is the same as what I've been trying to do. Clicking on an item still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Actually you are missing there `super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);`

Comment: It is empty in the `ListFragment`.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Working ?

Comment: Yes. `getItemAtPosition` was failing with an exception.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Ohhh.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your ListView Layout

```
android:clickable="true"
```

And Implement listView.setOnItemClickListener in your ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your items parent layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

it has three option `afterDescendants`, `beforeDescendants` and `blocksDescendants`. You should use one of them, it will work.

Comment: The correct attribute is "blocksDescendants" instead of "blockDescendants"